# Where can I find sources on a QED partial reflection experiment?

Tags: experimental-physics, resource-recommendations, quantum-electrodynamics

In "QED: the strange theory of light and matter" Richard Feynman describes a thought experiment where a glass block and two photomultiplier tubes are set up so that he can calculate the percentage transmitted vs the percentage reflected at the front and back boundary.

[image]

He then varies the thickness of the glass to achieve a sinusoidal correlation between thickness and probability. He states that this correlation has been proved experimentally up to 50 meters.

[image]

If anyone knows of this experiment being done in real life, I would love it if you could send me an article about it or let me know where I could possibly look to find it myself.

Comment: This is a common experiment for student optics labs nowadays

Comment: OK, thank you very much.